# Golang error inside docker

Tags: docker, go, go-gorm

I get a strange error in docker when building my go app:

```
./main.go:31:9: cannot use db (type *"github.com/khwerhahn/somerepo/vendor/github.com/jinzhu/gorm".DB) as type *"app/vendor/github.com/jinzhu/gorm".DB in argument to Migrate  
The command '/bin/sh -c go-wrapper install' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Could somebody hint me into the right direction, because locally the app runs just fine. Its just inside the docker container. I use `glide` to manage dependencies.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.9
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install

CMD ["go-wrapper", "run"]
```

//// Edit
This is how my structure looks. `Glide` manages the vendor folder. The docker build does the rest.

[image]

Comment: Seems you are importing gorm both from vendor directory and gopath and there is a mismatch. Provide more details about how did you do your vendoring.

Comment: You should only have a vendor directory in the top level of your project. Imported packed need to have vendored packages hoisted to the top level vendor directory.

Comment: I have added my project folder structure. I'm not doing much much more then the using glide to put deps into /vendor and then having the above docker build steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `go get` is called by `go-wrapper download`. This fetches the dependencies from the remote instead of looking in the vendor folder.

If your libraries are already vendored and the code is in the `vendor` folder, all you should have to do is `go run` or `go install`.

and why do you need go-wrapper when you can just do.

```
RUN glide install
RUN go install
WORKDIR "../bin"
RUN myapp
```